# single word to define the following : a deep desire to become the king of a kingdom

Tags: word-choice

When a person has an obsessive desire towards the power (or throne) of a kingdom
`a deep desire to become the king of a kingdom`. When I used google translate to get the word it showed me `Aspiration for monarchy` as the word. But I believe there could be a better word to fit the meaning.

Comment: Are you talking about a person who is likely to become king (the prince of the kingdom)  or are you talking about a random non-royal person who wants (irrationally) to be king?

Comment: Referring to the prince of the kingdom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An adjective for that is "power-hungry", though it's more general than just the desire to be king.

Comment: 'Power-hungry' is the word, but that didn't strike me directly, I was looking to coin the word from a different perspective. End of the day you answered my question correctly.